# Why is my JupyterLab not launching with a Python3 Kernel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I installed JupyterLab on my desktop and Python 4.11 from the Microsoft Store. I verified that I have the latest version of JupyterLab installed. When I launch the JupyterLab app, I'm getting some weird error "Jupyter Server process terminated before the initialization completed" (screenshot) [failed to intialize error in jupyterlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkU9a.png)

When I try to launch JupyterLab from the Command Prompt window by typing "py -m jupyterlab --no-browser" it says that "no module named JupyerLab exists (see screenshot). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l338g.png) even though I have it installed.

Have been reading different threads and troubleshooting for hours but no clue what could be causing this issue. Wondering if anyone has any ideas here. Thank you.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing both JupyterLab and Python 4.11, and adding the path to the Environment Variables tab, to no avail. Unable to open a notebook with the Python kernel.

Comment: `python 4.11` ???

Comment: There is no version 4 of Python. Do you mean 3.11 instead?